# Now to structure return parameter to accept boolean values with XMLService?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg, php-toolkit

I am trying to call an RPGLE service program from PHP using the [PHP Toolkit](http://youngiprofessionals.com/wiki/XMLSERVICE). The procedure returns a data structure that includes an element of type `N` (indicator) and returns either `*off` or `*on`.

I am trying to figure out how to structure my return parameter in PHP to accept a value of this type and cannot find any information about sending or receiving boolean values with XMLService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted [Alan Seiden](http://www.alanseiden.com/toolkit/) with this question and his answer fixed my issue.

You can use a 1-byte character parameter in place of a specialized indicator type. For example:

Input

```
$params[] = $toolkit->AddParameterChar('in', 1, 'My indicator', 'MYIND', '0');
```

Output

```
$retVal = $toolkit->AddParameterChar('out', 1, 'My indicator', 'MYIND');
```

The XML (for an output param) will come back like:

```
<return io='out' comment='My indicator'>
    <data var='MYIND' type='1A' ><![CDATA[0]]></data> 
</return>
```

Which yields PHP in the $result['retvals'] of:

```
array(1) { ["MYIND"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

Which will evaluate to true/false (1/0) correctly as long as you don't type check.

Thank you very much Alan!

Comment: Or since it is usually better to use === or !== to compare values, just make sure you check against a string '1' or '0'. The indicator data type is, after all, just a character type with a value of either '1' or '0'.